# knockout template to show/hide base on data received

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use a common knockout template.  The data returned will depend on what was selected in one of the search filters.  As of now whatever is selected the DOB TD is shown along with the other TDs.  I want to show/hide the TDs based on the selection.  How do I do this?

**Part of the observables**

```
self.SearchByVal = ko.observable("");  // Holds the value of the filter selected
self.SearchByVal(document.getElementById("<%=ddlSearchBy.ClientID%>").value);  // Hold the selected value.
```

The selected value can be **DOB, JoinDate, RetirementDate**.

**The HTML**

```
<table width="100%" id="tblSearchResults" data-bind="visible: SearchResults().length>0">
    <thead >
        <tr >
            <th align="left">Employee Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th align="left" data-bind="text:SearchByVal"></th>  
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
         <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="EmployeeDetails" data-bind="template: { name:'TmplSearchResults', foreach: SearchResults }">
                                </tbody>

    </table>
```

**The Template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="TmplSearchResults">  
 <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;" >
        <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" data-bind="text: gender"></td>
        if (self.SearchByVal() == "DOB") {  //<-- I tired this but shows in all cases
              <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: dob"></td> 
        } 
        if (self.SearchByVal() == "JoinDate") {  //<-- This also shows when DOB is selected
              <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: JoinDate"></td> 
        } 
    </tr>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use knockouts if binding handler, not the standard JavaScript version -

```
<div data-bind="if: SearchByVal() === 'DOB'">
    //content
</div>
```

also as shown you don't need to use self. To reference anything in he current context.  Also you may want to check out containerless bindings as shown in the if binding doc

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Containerless binding example -

```
<script type="text/html" id="TmplSearchResults">  
 <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;" >
        <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" data-bind="text: gender"></td>
        <!--ko if: (SearchByVal() == "DOB") -->
              <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: dob"></td> 
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--ko if: (SearchByVal() == "JoinDate") -->
              <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: JoinDate"></td> 
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>  
</script>
```

Comment: Just add additional handlers with if.  If you use them inside of a container less binding you can add as many as you want with zero additional markup rendered.  I am on my phone or I would show more markup, but should be easy enough to deduce from the answer

Comment: Threw in a containerless binding example.

Comment: I tried the above but get an error Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: if: (self.SearchByVal() == "DOB") 
Message: Object [object global] has no method 'SearchByVal'

Comment: If I try like this way the error does not come but the DOB value is not shown
 <!-- ko if: (self.SearchByVal == "DOB") -->
                  <td valign="middle" data-bind="text: DOB"></td> 
           <!-- /ko -->

Comment: Yes, in my example I clearly stated you need to remove the self. because you are already in the context of the view model, and then I subsequently left it in my example : )  Remove the self. and it will work

Comment: I tried that but got a message SearchByVal is not defined.  I add $root.SearchByVal== and it works